# Why does Analyzing Speech Recognition Results On-The-Fly Crash Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, voice-recognition, webspeech-api

I'm using Javascript's Web Speech API to do simple speech analysis on the fly, but it keeps crashing Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.80). It runs for about 30 seconds and then freezes up. I have interimResults set to true, and I have an event listener on 'end' which fires start() but upon console logging I see that it doesn't over-fire, it simply fires a single time on 'end', which is every 5 seconds or so. After that the following code analyzes the input to search among 2 short arrays for words and word combinations, but it eventually crashes the browser. What am I doing incorrectly?

```js
function analyzeSpeech(transcript) {

    let i, j;

    const positives = [`love`, `like`, `wonderful`, `amazing`, `loves`, `happy`, `proud`, `delighted`, `cool`];
    const negations = [`don't`, `didn't`, `won't`];

    for (i = 0; i < positives.length; i++) { //For each word in the positives array...

        if (transcript.includes(positives[i])) { //...if transcript has that positive word...

            for (j = 0; j < negations.length; j++) { //...then for each word in the negation array...
                let transNegationsIndex = transcript.split(' ').indexOf(`${negations[j]}`);
                let transPositiveIndex = transcript.split(' ').indexOf(`${positives[i]}`)

                if ((transNegationsIndex + 1 === transPositiveIndex) || (transNegationsIndex + 2 === transPositiveIndex)) { //...if the negation comes soon before the positive word...
                    console.log(`${negations[j]} ${positives[i]}`) //...console log those two words...
                    return;
                } else { //...else console log the positive word by itself.
                    console.log(positives[i])
                    return;
                }

            }

        }

    };
```